# C++ mixin constructor arguments

Tags: c++

I'm currently experimenting with the implementation of mixin classes in C++. I almost have the behavior that I want. However there's one issue concerning the passing through of the mixin's base class arguments: If the base class requires a const reference to a non-copyable object then the code fails to compile.

As you can see in the code sample below. The class `WidgetBase` compiles fine and `MetaWidgetBase` gets a compiler error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class WidgetBase
{
public:
    WidgetBase(WidgetBase * inParent, const std::string & inTitle) :
        mParent(inParent),
        mTitle(inTitle)
    {
    }

    virtual ~WidgetBase() { }

private:
    WidgetBase * mParent;
    std::string mTitle;
};

class MetaWidgetBase
{
public:
    MetaWidgetBase(const std::type_info & inTypeInfo) : mTypeInfo(inTypeInfo) {}

    virtual ~MetaWidgetBase(){}

private:
    const std::type_info & mTypeInfo;
};

template<class SuperType>
class Resizable : public SuperType
{
    typedef SuperType Super;

public:
    void resize(int width, int height) {}

protected:
    Resizable() {}

    template<class Arg0>
    Resizable(Arg0 arg0) : Super(arg0) {}

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1>
    Resizable(Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1) : Super(arg0, arg1) {}

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1, class Arg2>
    Resizable(Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) : Super(arg0, arg1, arg2) {}

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1, class Arg2, class Arg3>
    Resizable(Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, Arg3 arg3) : Super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3) {}
};

template<class SuperType>
class Movable : public SuperType
{
    typedef SuperType Super;

public:
    void move(int x, int y) {}

protected:
    Movable() {}

    template<class Arg0>
    Movable(Arg0 arg0) : Super(arg0) {}

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1>
    Movable(Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1) : Super(arg0, arg1) {}

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1, class Arg2>
    Movable(Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) : Super(arg0, arg1, arg2) {}

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1, class Arg2, class Arg3>
    Movable(Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, Arg3 arg3) : Super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3) {}
};


class MyWidget : public Resizable<Movable<WidgetBase> >
{
    typedef Resizable<Movable<WidgetBase> > Super;

public:
    MyWidget(WidgetBase * inParent, const std::string & inTitle) :
        Super(inParent, inTitle)
    {
    }
};


class MyMetaWidget : public Resizable<MetaWidgetBase>
{
    typedef Resizable<MetaWidgetBase> Super;

public:
    MyMetaWidget() :
        Super(typeid(this))
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Works fine:
    MyWidget widget(NULL, "Hello");

    // Error: std::type_info has private copy constructor!
    MyMetaWidget metaWidget;

    return 0;
}
```

Exact error message is:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/typeinfo: In constructor 'MyMetaWidget::MyMetaWidget()':
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/typeinfo:135: error: 'std::type_info::type_info(const std::type_info&)' is private
```

My current workaround is to pass the std::type_info object as a const pointer instead of a const reference.

Does anyone how to handle this problem properly?

### Update

It seems that during the forwarding the template arguments only loose the reference  part of their type signature. The rest remains unharmed. This also implies that if we use "ArgN &" as argument type, we are safe.

So basically the solution is this: have the constructor of the mixin class take all its arguments as non-const references.

Here's my sample application that tests various combinations(GCC):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

#define TRACE std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl << std::flush;
#define TRACE_MIXIN std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl << std::flush;
#define TRACE_BASE std::cout << "\n" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl << std::flush;

// Savable is a mixin class for saving object state to file.
template<class BaseType>
struct Savable : public BaseType {
    Savable() {
        TRACE_MIXIN
    }

    template<class Arg0>
    Savable(Arg0 & arg0) : BaseType(arg0) {
        TRACE_MIXIN
    }

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1>
    Savable(Arg0 & arg0, Arg1 & arg1) : BaseType(arg0, arg1) {
        TRACE_MIXIN
    }

    void Save(const std::string & inFileName) {}
};

// Loadable is a mixin class for load object state from file.
template<class BaseType>
struct Loadable : public BaseType {
    Loadable() {
        TRACE_MIXIN
    }

    template<class Arg0>
    Loadable(Arg0 & arg0) : BaseType(arg0) {
        TRACE_MIXIN
    }

    template<class Arg0, class Arg1>
    Loadable(Arg0 & arg0, Arg1 & arg1) : BaseType(arg0, arg1) {
        TRACE_MIXIN
    }

    void Load(const std::string & inFileName) {}
};

// Test with a copyable constructor args
namespace CopyLand {

struct MyObject  {}; // copyable

struct ValueBase {
    ValueBase(MyObject inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    MyObject mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct ConstValueBase {
    ConstValueBase(const MyObject inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    const MyObject mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct PtrBase {
    PtrBase(MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    MyObject * mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct ConstPtrBase {
    ConstPtrBase(const MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    const MyObject * mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct RefBase {
    RefBase(MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    MyObject & mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct ConstRefBase {
    ConstRefBase(const MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    const MyObject & mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct LoadableAndSavableValueBase : public Loadable<Savable<ValueBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableValueBase(MyObject inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<ValueBase> >(inObject, inTest) {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavableConstValueBase : public Loadable<Savable<ConstValueBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableConstValueBase(const MyObject inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<ConstValueBase> >(inObject, inTest) {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavablePtrBase : public Loadable<Savable<PtrBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavablePtrBase(MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<PtrBase> >(inObject, inTest) {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavableRefBase : public Loadable<Savable<RefBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableRefBase(MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<RefBase> >(inObject, inTest) {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase : public Loadable<Savable<ConstPtrBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase(const MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<ConstPtrBase> >(inObject, inTest) {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase : public Loadable<Savable<ConstRefBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase(const MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<ConstRefBase> >(inObject, inTest) {
        TRACE
    }
};

void test() {
    MyObject myObject;
    LoadableAndSavableValueBase valueBase(myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableConstValueBase constValueBase(myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavablePtrBase ptrBase(&myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase constPtrBase(&myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableRefBase refBase(myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase constRefBase(myObject, "Test");
}

} // namespace CopyLand

namespace NoCopyLand { // Test with a noncopyable Arg0 object

struct MyObject {
    MyObject() {}

    // noncopyable
    MyObject(const MyObject&);
    const MyObject& operator=(const MyObject&);
};

struct PtrBase {
    PtrBase(MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    MyObject * mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct ConstPtrBase {
    ConstPtrBase(const MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    const MyObject * mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct RefBase {
    RefBase(MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    MyObject & mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct ConstRefBase {
    ConstRefBase(const MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        mObject(inObject), mTest(inTest) {
        TRACE_BASE
    }
    const MyObject & mObject;
    std::string mTest;
};

struct LoadableAndSavablePtrBase : public Loadable<Savable<PtrBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavablePtrBase(MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<PtrBase> >(inObject, inTest)  {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavableRefBase : public Loadable<Savable<RefBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableRefBase(MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<RefBase> >(inObject, inTest)  {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase : public Loadable<Savable<ConstPtrBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase(const MyObject * inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<ConstPtrBase> >(inObject, inTest)  {
        TRACE
    }
};

struct LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase : public Loadable<Savable<ConstRefBase> > {
    LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase(const MyObject & inObject, const std::string & inTest) :
        Loadable<Savable<ConstRefBase> >(inObject, inTest)  {
        TRACE
    }
};

// Also include a test with std::type_info.
struct TypeInfo {
    TypeInfo(const std::type_info & inTypeInfo) : mTypeInfo(inTypeInfo) {}

    const std::type_info & mTypeInfo;
};

struct LoadableAndSavableTypeInfo : public Loadable<Savable<TypeInfo> > {
    LoadableAndSavableTypeInfo() : Loadable<Savable<TypeInfo> >(typeid(this)) {}
};

void test() {
    MyObject myObject;
    LoadableAndSavablePtrBase ptrBase(&myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase constPtrBase(&myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableRefBase refBase(myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase constRefBase(myObject, "Test");
    LoadableAndSavableTypeInfo typeInfo;
    typeInfo.mTypeInfo.name(); // get the std::type_info
}

} // namespace NoCopyLand

int main() {
    CopyLand::test();
    NoCopyLand::test();
    return 0;
}
```

When running the program it produces the following output:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp

CopyLand::ValueBase::ValueBase(CopyLand::MyObject, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = CopyLand::ValueBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<CopyLand::ValueBase>]
CopyLand::LoadableAndSavableValueBase::LoadableAndSavableValueBase(CopyLand::MyObject, const std::string&)

CopyLand::ConstValueBase::ConstValueBase(CopyLand::MyObject, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = CopyLand::ConstValueBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<CopyLand::ConstValueBase>]
CopyLand::LoadableAndSavableConstValueBase::LoadableAndSavableConstValueBase(CopyLand::MyObject, const std::string&)

CopyLand::PtrBase::PtrBase(CopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = CopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = CopyLand::PtrBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = CopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<CopyLand::PtrBase>]
CopyLand::LoadableAndSavablePtrBase::LoadableAndSavablePtrBase(CopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)

CopyLand::ConstPtrBase::ConstPtrBase(const CopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const CopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = CopyLand::ConstPtrBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const CopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<CopyLand::ConstPtrBase>]
CopyLand::LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase::LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase(const CopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)

CopyLand::RefBase::RefBase(CopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = CopyLand::RefBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<CopyLand::RefBase>]
CopyLand::LoadableAndSavableRefBase::LoadableAndSavableRefBase(CopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)

CopyLand::ConstRefBase::ConstRefBase(const CopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = CopyLand::ConstRefBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const CopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<CopyLand::ConstRefBase>]
CopyLand::LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase::LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase(const CopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)

NoCopyLand::PtrBase::PtrBase(NoCopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = NoCopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = NoCopyLand::PtrBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = NoCopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<NoCopyLand::PtrBase>]
NoCopyLand::LoadableAndSavablePtrBase::LoadableAndSavablePtrBase(NoCopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)

NoCopyLand::ConstPtrBase::ConstPtrBase(const NoCopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const NoCopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = NoCopyLand::ConstPtrBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const NoCopyLand::MyObject*, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<NoCopyLand::ConstPtrBase>]
NoCopyLand::LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase::LoadableAndSavableConstPtrBase(const NoCopyLand::MyObject*, const std::string&)

NoCopyLand::RefBase::RefBase(NoCopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = NoCopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = NoCopyLand::RefBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = NoCopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<NoCopyLand::RefBase>]
NoCopyLand::LoadableAndSavableRefBase::LoadableAndSavableRefBase(NoCopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)

NoCopyLand::ConstRefBase::ConstRefBase(const NoCopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const NoCopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = NoCopyLand::ConstRefBase]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&, Arg1&) [with Arg0 = const NoCopyLand::MyObject, Arg1 = const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, BaseType = Savable<NoCopyLand::ConstRefBase>]
NoCopyLand::LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase::LoadableAndSavableConstRefBase(const NoCopyLand::MyObject&, const std::string&)
Savable<BaseType>::Savable(Arg0&) [with Arg0 = const std::type_info, BaseType = NoCopyLand::TypeInfo]
Loadable<BaseType>::Loadable(Arg0&) [with Arg0 = const std::type_info, BaseType = Savable<NoCopyLand::TypeInfo>]
```

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in my example or in my conclusion :)

Answer (score 2):

You're taking `ArgN` by value in the mixin classes. You could try `Movable(Arg0 const& arg0, Arg1 const& arg1)` and likewise for `Resizable`.

Comment: I think that will solve the problem for a few case and cause issues in other cases (non-const refs). Anyway, thanks for your ansewer. I'll do some experiments to see how far this gets me.

Comment: @StackedCrooked : The proper answer is to use a newer compiler that has r-value reference support. Then your `Resizable` and `Movable` implementations can use perfect forwarding for the constructors (i.e., work with both const and non-const references without an exponential number of overloads).

Comment: @ildjarn check my post. Apparently it's only the 'ref'-part of the type that gets lost in the forwarding. And a workaround is to let the mixin take all args by ref. Btw, I agree the new C++ features should be preferred, but unfortunately I think it will take few years until GCC will be upgraded at my current job.. :